# Uniform unboundedness of linear operators

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, dynamical-systems

**Question:**
Suppose that $(T_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of invertible linear operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \{0\}$, we have $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \|T_k x\| = \infty .$$

Let $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ denote the unit sphere. Then does it follow that $$\lim_{k\to \infty} \inf_{x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}}\|T_k x\| = \infty? $$

Stated another way, is the sequence uniformly unbounded on the unit sphere?

**Some of my thoughts so far:**

**(1)** My question seems *almost* (but not quite) the converse of the  [Banach-Steinhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) in the special setting of finite-dimensional vector spaces.

**(2)** Uniform unboundedness in the above question is equivalent to convergence of the sequence $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \frac{1}{\|T_k x\|} = 0.$$
If I could prove that the sequence $(1/\|T_k x\|)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ (with $x$ in the unit sphere) was uniformly bounded and [equicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity), then the [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem) together with pointwise convergence of $(1/\|T_k x\|)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ to zero would imply the result.

**(3)** Since we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we may write $T_k$ in terms of its [singular value decomposition (SVD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition): $T_k = U_k \Sigma_k V_k^T$. If $\|T_k x\|$ did not tend uniformly to $\infty$ on the unit sphere, then the smallest singular values of $\Sigma_k$ would have to be bounded, say, by $K > 0$. Denoting by $v_k^n$ the last column of $V_k$, we then have that $\forall k: \|T_k v_k^n\| < K$. Compactness of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ would then allow me to extract a convergent subsequence from $(v_k^n)_{k=1}^\infty$, but I'm not sure how to make this useful.

**(4)** A geometric interpretation of my question is the following. For each $k$, the image of the unit sphere $T_k(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$ is an ellipsoid $E_k$. The hypothesis that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}: \lim_{k\to \infty} \|T_k x\| = \infty$ implies that for any point $x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, the sequence of points $T_k x \in E_k$ grows unbounded in norm. It then seems geometrically intuitive to me that this can only happen if the length of the smallest "semi-axis" of the ellipsoids $E_k$ tend to $\infty$, which is equivalent to saying that $\lim_{k\to \infty} \inf_{x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}}\|T_k x\| = \infty. $ However, I haven't been able to turn this into a proof, and perhaps my intuition is misguided.

**Why I care:** I am reading the book [Normally Hyperbolic Invariant Manifolds in Dynamical Systems](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387942056) by Stephen Wiggins. In deriving equation 3.5 while proving [Lemma 3.1.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=StTTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=wiggins+lemma+3.1.1&source=bl&ots=MN_LSIx0En&sig=kh7FmZl4fLfyP9wH96EHFxM-Djw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEgOSmgLzMAhVMRCYKHWGxAssQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=wiggins%20lemma%203.1.1&f=false), he seems to be asserting the validity of the inference I am asking about.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, thank you for pointing that out. I (hopefully) fixed all of the offending statements above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $T_k x = k^2 x_1 -k x_2$. Then for any $x \neq 0$ we see that $|T_kx| \to \infty$.

However, $T_k ({1 \over \sqrt{1 + k^2}}(1,k)) = 0$ for all $k$.

Comment: I was typing an answer with $k^2 x_1 + k x_2$ ;) In case the OP wants invertible operators $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, just add a second component $x_2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That's funny, I am usually the slowest!

Comment: Let's pretend you started typing before I did.

Comment: Further evidence that I need to waste less time trying to prove impossible statements and more time on looking for counterexamples.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Almost certainly!

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim: I have had my intuition thwarted so many times that I would say you need to split your time between looking and trying to prove!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case $n=2$, and take $$T_k = \pmatrix{k^2 \sin(1/k) & k^2 \cos(1/k)\cr 0 & 1\cr}$$
Write $x \in \mathbb S^1$ as $\pmatrix{\cos(\theta)\cr \sin(\theta)}$, and note that $(T_k x)_1 = k^2 \sin(\theta + 1/k)$.  If $\sin(\theta) = 0$ this is $\pm k + O(1)$, while if $\sin(\theta) \ne 0$ it is $k^2 \sin(\theta) + O(k)$.
So $\|T_k x\| \to \infty$ for any $x$.  On the other hand, $$T_k \pmatrix{\cos(-1/k)\cr \sin(-1/k)} = \pmatrix{0 \cr \sin(-1/k)}$$ are bounded.

Comment: I accepted the other answer since it came first, but this is also helpful. Thank you.